# change two files with different date format

Tags: shell, unix, sh, unix-timestamp

I want to compare two files using diff command. However, due to different date format in both the files it not compared

**File1**

```
394|a101|2019-04-08 09:45:01|2019-04-08 09:45:01
389|a102|2019-04-08 09:46:02|2019-04-08 09:46:02
```

**Files2**

```
394|a101|20190408094501000000|20190408094501000000
389|a102|20190408094602000000|20190408094602000000
```

Above both the files are same but only date format is different.

I have tried to remove Hyphen & Colon from the string and then compare but it might possible that same symbol might available in other columns

Plz suggest how can I compare both files. (Date columns comes on any position in file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### general thoughts:

- better optimize your data sources
- verify both sides work on UTC or same time zone

### How you might easily do it:

either rectify values A or values B:

( here the example for converting A ,since that's more reliable when you can anchor on : and - )

```
cat filea|sed 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\) \([0-9][0-9]\):\([0-9][0-9]\):\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1\2\3\4\5\6000000/g'
```

OUTPUT:

```
394|a101|20190408094501000000|20190408094501000000
389|a102|20190408094602000000|20190408094602000000
```

---

example snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
replacetime() { sed 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\) \([0-9][0-9]\):\([0-9][0-9]\):\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1\2\3\4\5\6000000/g' ; } ;
cat FILEA | replacetime > /tmp/FILEA.tmp
diff /tmp/FILEA.tmp FILEB
```

Comment: Benji - it would be great help if you explain me above code. I have understood the first part to find the string but second Part (\1\2\3\4000000) is still confusing me.

Comment: basically : if you use \0 in sed it is "the whole match" ,  the sub pattern trick works similar  , in the search part you do `\(stringtofind1\)_thestring-between \(stringtofind2\) `, then you can use your matches like `\1 \2 \2` in the replacement part , the trailing zeros are added since it seems you have a flattened timestamp (6 zeros at the end )

Comment: Thank you Benji for your support. I have marked your answer

Comment: Hi Benji, I need your support here. I have used above command but just only difference is I have used Filename in variable and it give me an error "Cat can not open file".

Comment: File1=test.csv                                                                                            
 replacetime() { sed 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\) \([0-9][0-9]\):\([0-9][0-9]\):\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1\2\3\4\5\6000000/g' ; } ;
cat $FIle1 | replacetime > /tmp/FILEA.tmp
diff /tmp/FILEA.tmp FILEB

Comment: $file1 is a variable name, it would be `cat test.csv  | replacetime `

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{for(i=3;i<=4;i++)if(gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$i))$i=$i "000000"}1' file1 |
diff - file2
```

Awk explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN{        
    FS=OFS="|"                    # set field separators
}
{
    for(i=3;i<=4;i++)             # fields 3 and 4
        if(gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$i))  # remove non-digits
            $i=$i "000000"        # if any were removed, fill with zeroes
}1' file1                         # output
```

Output is then piped to diff: `awk ... file1 | diff - file2`

Comment: Thank for explanation & also code is working fine. However if no data available in date field then also above code replace null with 000000 number.

Comment: Yeah, there is no checking as the sample data did not give hints that it would be needed. I'll fix it, just a sec.